# How to calculate binary SHA256 hash for given hex data in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to generate SHA256 signature for a given "hex data" (Binary) using Crypto++. Can anybody share the code? I found a similar question "Can anybody give me a working example of generating a SHA256 hash in C++ with Crypto++,..." , but that uses "string" as input & return string. I would also like to know if the string hash of "123" can be converted into Binary hash of "123" (I mean any input. "123" being just an example")? ( I used http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm to check that the string hash of 123 is a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3 AND the binary hash of 123 is 3d73c0c831c942c1996ca667b639970e571d58c6b7b996e4082a6d091be0b956)

Comment: Using [tag:c++], [tag:crypto++] and [tag:sha256] in the search gives me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20crypto%2b%2b%20sha256

Comment: Sharmesh got Homework?

Comment: Hi Olaf Dietsche, the tags you are stating do not provide any clue to me how to generate binary SHA256 hash using Cryptopp. Please provide detailed answer as I am newbie for C++

Answer (score 0):

Crypto++ hash functions work with arrays of bytes. That's why you can hash string - because it's array of bytes.
So you can process your array of bytes and then apply same algorithm to convert result to string.

"String" hash can't be converted into "binary" hash, because in fact it's both binary hashes with different binary data.